# qTip in ajax content

Tags: ajax, qtip

I load some ajax content with the *load* jquery function and qTip is no more working for elements in the ajax content.

I dealt with the *live* jquery function for the other jquery event but I don't know how to proceed with qTip.

```
//Load part
$(".load_trigger").load("page.php");

// Tooltip part
$(".content_el").each(function(){
      jQuery(".trigger_el", this).qtip({   

         content:...
});
});
```

Any idea ?

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that qTip has a built-in functionality to do that, no need to load (see [here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/tutorials/#dynamic)).

If you still need to use `$(".load_trigger").load("page.php");` did you tried something like : `content: $('.load_trigger').html()` ?